# Error installing Google APIs Intel x86_64 Atom System Image

Tags: android-studio, sdk, updates

The Android Studio keeps asking to update Google APIs Intel x86_64 Atom System Image but after downloading successfully the installation fails.

This the error I encounter:

> An error occurred during installation:
> C:\Users\jetbe\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\system-images\android-34\google_apis\x86_64\system.img: The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.
> "Install Google APIs Intel x86_64 Atom System Image API 34 (revision 11)" complete.
> "Install Google APIs Intel x86_64 Atom System Image API 34 (revision 11)" failed.
> Failed packages:
> - Google APIs Intel x86_64 Atom System Image (system-images;android-34;google_apis;x86_64)

I have one project opened. If I close it, the AS goes to a Main screen, but I can't find how to execute the SDK update.

Answer (score 0):

I found what was using the file.

Even though the Project Program was not running, I found that the Emulator was still running after the Proyect stopped.

I went to the Device Manager and found the device in running state. After I clicked the Square to stop it I waited for the Arrow to appear. Then executed the Update successfully.